# Independent set in Berge graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm just a programmer. 
I just wonder if there is out there a free charge paper describing an algorithm for finding an independent set in a Berge graph(polynomial time of course :) ).
Thank you in advance for any hint.
Catalin

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.zib.de/groetschel/pubnew/paper/groetschellovaszschrijver1988.pdf

See the chapter 9, "Stable sets in graphs"

Comment: Thank u man.ijust discovered that paper ... But it's so technical .... I tried to read about Elipsoid algo and stuff but it's killing me. I try to find some simpler approaching .... Some implemented already algo. Like starting with a graph G a d eliminating some vertices etc. I found  in other paper omething like this:"

Comment: alpha G1 = alpha G - 1; put the removed vx back; it must belong to maximum independent set. Otherwise leave it out. 3. Repeat for the rest of vx in new graph. 4. The max independent set will remain at the end" But the Cite start with "Since we can compute alpha on perfect graphs we can also find an independent set of size alpha in popolynomial time". My ask was for how to algo " compute alpha on perfect graphs". Again thank u in adadvance.

Comment: "1 Remove a vx from graph G. 2. Calculate alpha G=> G1.If ( see above)

Comment: On independent sets, a nice chapter (http://www.dharwadker.org/independent_set/). On Berge graphs (https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/08/28/23/PDF/B06002.pdf)